# Logout user on expired JWT token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to log out a user when the jwt token expires. I am trying to do it with axios interceptors, with the following code, but I get an infinite loop since it's asynchronous. Would anyone be able to tell how to go about it or if there is a better way? Thank you

```
 axios.interceptors.request.use(async (req) => {
    if (token) {
      const userToken = jwt_decoder(token);
      const isExpired = userToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now();
      if (!isExpired) return req;

      axios
        .delete("users/sign_out")
        .then((resp) => {
          clearLocalStorage();
        })

        .catch((err) => {
          clearLocalStorage();
        });
    }
    return req;
  });
```

Comment: I would advice against doing this client side, this code could easily be modified to bypass the expiration date check by the client itself. A more common practice is having your webserver return a 401 unauthorized (additionally with a "Token-Expired" header present) when the token has expired, which your client can then pick up and start the refresh token flow.

Comment: @nbokmans thank you for your reply. I don't have access to the backend, and this is supposed to be a temporary solution

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the local storage before making the delete API call should stop the infinite loop. As it won't enter the if condition during the delete API call.
Try this.

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(async (req) => {
    if (token) {
      const userToken = jwt_decoder(token);
      const isExpired = userToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now();
      if (!isExpired) return req
      
      clearLocalStorage();
      axios
        .delete("users/sign_out")
        .then((resp) => {
          clearLocalStorage();
        })

        .catch((err) => {
          clearLocalStorage();
        });
       return req;
     }
    return req;
  });
```

But as the comment on your question it is not advisable to carry out this check on the client. rather use the status code 401 (unauthorised)

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: does it still loop infinitely ? Or is there an error that is stopping it ?

Comment: Still an infinite loop. I think I solved it by checking the response with axios interceptors rather than the request, and check if the status is 401 and the jwt token is expired

Answer (score -1):

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(async (req) => {
    if (token) {
      const userToken = jwt_decoder(token);
      const isExpired = userToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now();
      if (!isExpired) return req;
      try {
       const resp = await axios.delete("users/sign_out");
        clearLocalStorage();
      } catch(e) {
       clearLocalStorage();
      }
    }
    return req;
  });
```